# Understanding _tf_sess()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am reading a reproducible code from a Google Brain research paper and I am struggling to understand it.

Inside the MonitoredSession, an ambiguous `sess._tf_sess()` is used. Unfortunately, there is nothing mentioned in the documentation about this function.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/anonymous-iclr-2019/acai-iclr-2019/blob/master/lib/train.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonitoredSession` is a wrapper over the basic `tf.Session()`. `_tf_sess` is "private" method returning the basic session being wrapped: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/124e8eebc72994a3f1153a3f6465f3914523fc1a/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L842.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why is it used then in the mentioned example?    https://github.com/anonymous-iclr-2019/acai-iclr-2019/blob/master/lib/train.py

Comment: If you check the example, you will observe that self.sess is used along with self.tf_sess.

Comment: Why does he need two sessions?

Comment: It is not really two sessions (I am ignoring eval_sess). MonitoredSession is just a wrapper that adds some common logic on top of the base session object. Looks like authors needed to run some things that are not supported by the MonitoredSession APIs or just wanted to use the base session avoiding all the MonitoredSession logic in some cases.